# React with TypeScript using tsyringe for dependency injection

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rest, web, tsyringe

I am currently having trouble with my React TypeScript project.

I created my project with `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`.

I recently added tsyringe for dependency injection and was trying to implement it for an apiService. After following the readme(https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe#injecting-primitive-values-named-injection) for adding primitive values I have hit a block. I already add *experimentalDecorators* and *emitDecoratorMetadata* to my `tsconfig.json` file with no success.

The error actual error I am encountering is:

```
./src/ts/utils/NetworkService.ts 9:14
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (9:14)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| let NetworkService = (_dec = singleton(), _dec(_class = (_temp = class NetworkService {
>   constructor(@inject('SpecialString')
|   value) {
|     this.str = void 0;
```

I am fairly sure this problem is caused by Babel, however I created this with npm create react-app --template typescript and do not seem to have access to the Babel configuration.

*NetworkService.ts*

```
@singleton()
export default class NetworkService
{

    private str: string;
    constructor(@inject('SpecialString') value: string) {
        this.str = value;
    }
}
```

*Invocation method*

```
bob() 
{
    const inst = container.resolve(NetworkService);
}
```

Registering Class in index.ts

```
container.register('SpecialString', {useValue: 'https://myme.test'});


@registry([
    { token: NetworkService, useClass: NetworkService },
])
class RegisterService{}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React-Scripts manages many of the configs related to the project. For many cases, this is fine and actually a nice feature. However, because React-Scripts uses Babel for it's development environment and does not expose the config.

You have to **run** `npm run eject` to expose the configurations.

> Please note, this is a one-way operation and can not be undone.
> Personally, I prefer more control with my configuration.

After this you can **edit** the *webpack.config.js* in the newly created *config* folder.

**Find** the section related to the *babel-loader* in the *dev-environment* and **add** `'babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata'` to the *plugins array*.

Comment: Thanks for this! I wish this was included in the auto configuration.

Comment: I added the plugin: `plugins: [ isEnvDevelopment && shouldUseReactRefresh && require.resolve('react-refresh/babel'), require.resolve('babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata'), ]` but I still get the error: Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new'

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Jordan Schnur's reply, here are some more pitfalls I encountered when adding TSyringe to my CRA app:

## Use import type with @inject

If you get this error "TS1272: A type referenced in a decorated signature must be imported with 'import type' or a namespace import when 'isolatedModules' and 'emitDecoratorMetadata' are enabled." replace `import` with `import type` for the offending imports. You will encounter this when working with `@inject`
E.g. replace `import { IConfig } from "iconfig"` with `import type { IConfig } from "iconfig"`

## Fixing Jest

Your Jest tests will also break with TSyringe, especially when using `@inject`. I got the error "Jest encountered an unexpected token" with details `constructor(@((0, _tsyringe.inject)(""))` ("@" marked as the offending token). I took the following steps to fix that in CRA:

Add the line `import "reflect-metadata";` to the top of the file `src/setupTests.ts`

In `config/jest/babelTransform.js` replace line 18 and following:

From

```
    
    module.exports = babelJest.createTransformer({
      presets: [
        [
          require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app'),
          {
            runtime: hasJsxRuntime ? 'automatic' : 'classic',
          },
        ],
      ],
      babelrc: false,
      configFile: false,
    });
```

to:

```
    
    module.exports = babelJest.createTransformer({
      presets: [
        [
          require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app'),
          {
            runtime: hasJsxRuntime ? 'automatic' : 'classic',
          },
        ],
      ],
      plugins: [
        require.resolve('babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata')
      ],
      babelrc: false,
      configFile: false,
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created an simpler DI library that doesn't need decorators or polyfill. Works with CRA like a charm and has cool React bindings

[`iti`](https://itijs.org/)

```js
import { useContainer } from "./_containers/main-app"

function Profile() {
  const [auth, authErr] = useContainer().auth

  if (authErr) return <div>failed to load</div>
  if (!auth) return <div>loading...</div>

  return <div>hello {auth.profile.name}!</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of eject, you may use a lib that "overrides" some of your params.

I used craco : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco